# Javascript method does not work (neither JS nor HTML) in mobile format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile

I have a reddit-like app that allows users to vote for links with the [Activerecord Reputation System gem](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system).

I am trying to create a mobile version, based on [Railscast#199](http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices?view=comments), in which a `mobile.erb` format is used if the site is accessed via a mobile device.

The voting method works fine in the non-mobile format (defaults to javascript, but also works in html), but returns an error in mobile as follows. Note that it is trying to `Get` instead of `Post`.

```
Started GET "/links/98/vote?type=like" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-25 19:16:45 -0500
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/links/98/vote"):
```

What might be causing this? Is the `before_filter` preventing the javascript? How can I fix this?  Thanks much for your input!

**application_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :prepare_for_mobile

def prepare_for_mobile
  session[:mobile_param] = params[:mobile] if params[:mobile]
  request.format = :mobile if mobile_device?
end

def mobile_device?
  if session[:mobile_param]
    session[:mobile_param] == "1"
  else
    request.user_agent =~ /Mobile/
  end
end
helper_method :mobile_device?
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :links do
  member { post :vote }
end
```

**links_controller.rb**

```
def vote
  value = params[:type] == "like" ? 1 : 0
  @link = Link.find(params[:id])
  @link.add_or_update_evaluation(:link_votes, value, current_user)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.mobile { redirect_to :back }
    format.js
  end
end
```

**_link.mobile.erb**

```
<div id="link_<%= @link.id %>">
  <%= link_to "like", vote_link_path(@link, type: "like"), method: "post", remote: true %>
</div>

<div id="link_points_<%= @link.id %>">
  <%= @link.reputation_for(:link_votes).to_i %>
</div>
```

**vote.js.erb**

```
$('#link_<%= @link.id %>').html("<%= j link_to "up", vote_link_path(@link, type: "like"), method: "post", remote: true %>");


$('#link_points_<%= @link.id %>').html("<%= @link.reputation_for(:link_votes).to_i %>;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did:

**config/initializers/mime_types.rb**

```
Mime::Type.register_alias "text/html", :mobile
Mime::Type.register_alias "text/javascript", :mobilejs /* newly added mobilejs */
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :prepare_for_mobile

def prepare_for_mobile
  session[:mobile_param] = params[:mobile] if params[:mobile]
  if mobile_device?
    if request.format == :js
      request.format = :mobilejs /* newly added mobilejs format */
    else
      request.format = :mobile
    end
  end
end
```